# jQuery Mobile & UI - Animated form field clear?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I know it's quite an edge case so there's probably no (easy) way to do this, but is there either:

**A.** A way to empty the contents of an element (my textarea) with a nice little animation?

or

**B.** A way to do a sort of page curl animation where it looks as though the element and/or its contents are being peeled up, away, and out of the viewport as if it were paper?

Comment: Yes, both of those effects are possible with jQuery, CSS3 animations and/or a combination of both.